# how to get the value using linq query C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

How to get the value of authRoleCode= AHGENERAL   using linq query or lambda expression from below json. below the code i have provided the class strucure below this json. i have tried like this.

```
var str = request.ApplicationsAccess.CategoryAccessType.Where(x=>x.),
```

how to get the data data for it.

```
    "applicationsAccess": {
                            "categoryAccessType": [{
                                            "categoryCode": "Accident and Health",
                                            "basicApplications": {
                                                            "applictaionType": "basicApplications",
                                                            "roleAmpLabelAdded": [{
                                                                            "roleAMPLabel": "General access to marketing & resources",
                                                                            "authRoleCode": "AHGENERAL",
                                                                            "authRoleName": "A&H - General access to marketing & resources".
```

This is class structure, we are using for above json.

```
public partial class ApplicationsAccess
    {
        [JsonProperty("categoryAccessType")]
        public List<CategoryAccessTyp> CategoryAccessType { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class CategoryAccessTyp
    {
        [JsonProperty("categoryCode")]
        public string CategoryCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("applicationTypes")]
        public List<ApplicationType> ApplicationTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ApplicationType
    {
        [JsonProperty("applictaionType")]
        public string ApplictaionType { get; set; }
       
        public List<RoleAmpLabelAdded> RoleAmpLabelAdded { get; set; }
        
        public ApplicationsAdded ApplicationsAdded { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ApplicationsAdded
    {
        [JsonProperty("applications")]
        public List<Applications> Applications { get; set; }
    }

    

    public partial class RoleAmpLabelAdded
    {
        [JsonProperty("roleAMPLabel")]
        public string RoleAmpLabel { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("authRoleCode")]
        public string AuthRoleCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("authRoleName")]
        public string AuthRoleName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("applications")]
        public List<Applications> Applications { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class Applications
    {
        [JsonProperty("appId")]

        public long AppId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("appCode")]
        public long AppCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("appName")]
        public string AppName { get; set; }
    }
```

Please let us know in case you need more info
TIA.

Comment: What is the `request` object? Is it parsed JSON to the object model? And I don't quite get what exactly doesn't work. Could you please provide a code of what you're doing, how the `request` object is initialized. Additionally it would be great if you could provide an error message also.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo i have added class structure.

Comment: Thanks. What exactly do you need to get? The objects of the `RoleAmpLabelAdded ` class which has `AuthRoleCode ` equaled to `"AHGENERAL"`?

Comment: @E.Shcherbo yes

Answer (score 0):

If you need objects of `RoleAmpLabelAdded`  class which have the `AuthRoleCode` property equal to `"AHGENERAL"`, then you can try the following code:

```
 IEnumerable<RoleAmpLabelAdded> result = request
            .ApplicationAccess
            .CategoryAccessType
            .SelectMany(c => c.ApplicationTypes.SelectMany(t => t.RoleAmpLabelAdded))
            .Where(r => r.AuthRoleCode == "AHGENERAL");
```

To get all the `AuthRoleCode`-s:

```
       IEnumerable<string> result = request
            .ApplicationAccess
            .CategoryAccessType
            .SelectMany(c => c.ApplicationTypes.SelectMany(t => t.RoleAmpLabelAdded))
            .Select(r => r.AuthRoleCode);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can we get all the AuthRoleCode?

Comment: Sure, you just need to call `Select` one more time. I will update my answer.

Comment: i want all the authrole code not like AuthRoleCode == "AHGENERAL".